# I have three tables i want to combine and get the values of data in third table using jpa repository

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to java
I created three class in java i want to fetch the data in submodule class from the Module class and User class

1. User class
2. Module class
3. SubModule class

@Query("from SubModule s join Module m , User u where m.cId= :cId and u.id= :id")

please help to resolve the issue
Thanks

Comment: Please describe what's not working. Got any errors?

Comment: The join isn't on anything - you aren't telling it how or what in SubModule s joins to Module or User. Do you have mappings between them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.